# Adding numbers sequentially from a random sample

Tags: r, random, addition, sequential

I am trying to add 20 rnorm value outputs sequentially, with the first value being added onto 1000. How could I get each value to add onto the previous without it being 20 random rnorm values added onto 1000 as would be the case if I used this code below

```
storage1 <- rnorm(n=nyear, mean=1, sd=0.4)+1000
```

I am writing a loop so that each value will correspond with a year (from 1:20) as shown in the loop code below

```
N <- 1000
nyear <- 20
years <- 1:nyear
set.seed(101)
storage1 <- rnorm(n=nyear, mean=1, sd=0.4)+N
for (i in seq_along(years)) {
  print(paste("year",years[i],": reproduction=",storage1[i]))
}
```

Comment: Is this what you were trying to do: `cumsum(c(N, rnorm(nyear, mean=1, sd=0.4)))`.

Comment: Yes, thank you so much. This has helped me !